# How do I use apollo cache to match an input variable that is a sub array/sub list of ids?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

How do I use apollo cache to match an input variable that is a sub array/sub list of ids in the cache?

In particular, when I execute an apollo query, I want to return a response for a subset of list of params.

Phrased another way, how can I add additional entries into the cache so that my cache can match future "subqueries" e.g.

```
fetch({
    variables: {
        ids: ['1']
    }
})
```

when I had previously queried

```
fetch({
    variables: {
        ids: ['1', '2', '3']
    }
})
```

Full example below:

```
// This code is not working, but just used to illustrate an example.
const [fetch, data] = useQuery( /* graphql params here */ );

// Apollo cache will cache the response for `ids: ['1', '2', '3']`
fetch({
    variables: {
        ids: ['1', '2', '3']
    }
})

// In these subsequent call, I don't want to hit the server and want to hit the cache.
// Can I leverage apollo cache for this?
fetch({
    variables: {
        ids: ['1']
    }
})
fetch({
    variables: {
        ids: ['2','3']
    }
})
fetch({
    variables: {
        ids: ['1','2']
    }
})
```

Comment: Currently looking into these cache access strategies: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction.
Let's say fetch returns a list of people.

I am thinking of using `readFragment` to find cached data on people, and for people whose info are not in the cache, I'll call fetch on a subset of people id's.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use one of [Key arguments](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#specifying-key-arguments) or the [read function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#the-read-function) for the type in question.